# extjs: nested baseParams in request

Tags: ajax, extjs

In the frame of an Ajax request, I am trying to use a **nested** object for parameter "baseParams".  Basically, I would like to produce an URL like "ajax.php?**foo[controller]=demo&foo[action]=index**".

Bellow is the code that wrongly produces:  "ajax.php?**foo=[object]&foo=[object]**".

```
Ext.data.JsonStore(
    baseParams: {
        foo: {
            controller: 'demo',
            action: 'index'
        }
    },
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/ajax.php'
    }),
    (...)
);
```

Of course, I could write something like bellow but I was looking for a more nifty solution.

```
Ext.data.JsonStore(
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/ajax.php?foo[controller]=demo&foo[action]=index'
    }),
    (...)
);
```

After few attempts, I wonder if it is really possible. But maybe I missed something. Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

Or use something like this (which is better than a long url string):

```
baseParams: {
  'foo[controller]': 'demo',
  'foo[action]': 'index'
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works and I wonder why I haven't thought about this... It looks so obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this, which is identical in the end to Igor Pavelek's response, only a little more programmatic:

```
var foo = {
    'controller' : 'demo',
    'action' : 'index'
};

var gfObj = new Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters({paramPrefix: 'foo'});

var bp = gfObj.buildQuery(foo);

Ext.data.JsonStore({
    baseParams : bp,
    (...)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`baseParams: {
                    foo['controller']: 'demo',
                    foo['action']: 'index'
              }`

I would recommend this , i think there is simple difference of commas from above

Comment: I get a JavaScript parsing error with that syntax. It seems the quote must be around 'foo[controller]' to be working.